# Can one use MeshRefinementFunction to obtain a nonobtuse triangulation?

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

I have a planar convex polygonal region `Rc`. I would like to triangulate it such that
every triangle is nonobtuse. I was hoping that the `MeshRefinementFunction` option would indeed "refine the simplex" when the function (`fob` in my case) returns T, to quote the documentation.

```
 R = DiscretizeRegion[Rc
      , MeshRefinementFunction -> fob
      , MeshQualityGoal -> "Maximal"
      , PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]
```

But the above code does not in fact refine every triangle. E.g., 60 of the 478 triangles below are obtuse—not terribly obtuse, but obtuse (max angle approx. $113^\circ$).

---

[image: mesh]

---

I am aware that it is not straightforward to refine for nonobtuseness.
Does the meshing function just give up after a few tries?

By request, some ugly code for `fob`:

---

```
TriLengths[{a_, b_, c_}] := Module[{A, B, C},
   A = Sqrt[(b - a).(b - a)] // N;
   B = Sqrt[(c - b).(c - b)] // N;
   C = Sqrt[(a - c).(a - c)] // N;
   Return[{A, B, C}]
   ];
TriAngles[{a_, b_, c_}] := 
  Module[{A, B, C, \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]},
   {A, B, C} = TriLengths[{a, b, c}];
   \[Beta] = ArcCos[ (C^2 + A^2 - B^2)/(2 C A)] // N;
   \[Gamma] = ArcCos[ (A^2 + B^2 - C^2)/(2 A B)] // N;
   \[Alpha] = ArcCos[ (B^2 + C^2 - A^2)/(2 B C )] // N;
   Return[ { \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Alpha]}];
   ];
fob[vlist_, area_] := Module[{\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]},
   {\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]} = TriAngles[vlist] // N;
   If[Max[{\[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma]}] <= \[Pi]/2,
    Return[False],
    Return[True](*obtuse:refine*)
    ]];
(*Test*)
{a, b, c} = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 2}};
Print[TriAngles[{a, b, c}]];
fob[{a, b, c}, 999]
```

Comment: Giving a minimal working example would help.  In particular, can you write down what `fob` is?

Comment: @JessRiedel: I was afraid you'd ask. I'll have to untangle from my code...

Comment: You might find this tiny gem from Kahan useful: `tang[v1_?VectorQ, v2_?VectorQ, v3_?VectorQ] := Module[{n1 = Normalize[v1 - v2], n2 = Normalize[v3 - v2]}, 2 ArcTan[Norm[n1 + n2], Norm[n1 - n2]]]`. This determines the angle at vertex `v2`; you can then use `tang @@@ Partition[pts, 3, 1, 2]` to get all the angles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following works reasonably well, up to a minimum area cutoff that is needed to limit the evaluation time:

```
TriLengths[{a_, b_, c_}] := 
  Module[{A, B, C}, A = Sqrt[(b - a).(b - a)];
   B = Sqrt[(c - b).(c - b)];
   C = Sqrt[(a - c).(a - c)];
   {A, B, C}];
TriAngles[{a_, b_, c_}] := 
  Module[{A, B, C, α, β, γ}, {A, B, C} = 
    TriLengths[{a, b, c}];
   β = ArcCos[(C^2 + A^2 - B^2)/(2 C A)];
   γ = ArcCos[(A^2 + B^2 - C^2)/(2 A B)];
   α = ArcCos[(B^2 + C^2 - A^2)/(2 B C)];
   {β, γ, α}];

r = Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 2}];

DiscretizeRegion[r, 
 MeshRefinementFunction -> (#2 > .005 && 
     Evaluate@Max[TriAngles[#1]] > Pi/2 &)]
```

[image: mesh]

I tried to clean up the `TriAngles` function a little, but that formal issue wasn't the reason why it didn't work.

The main thing I did was to eliminate the `Module` wrapper around the calls to `TriAngles` and add `Evaluate` in front of the condition.

This seems to be necessary because the *parsing* of `MeshRefinementFunction` is unable to deal with the depth of scoping constructs in the original formulation. One could say this is a bug in the parsing.

For comparison, here is what the output of the above command looks like if you omit the `Evaluate`:

[image: mesh bad]

Note the obviously obtuse triangle in the upper left boundar region.

Comment: Just to be clear: I didn't try it *without* the area cutoff because the computation ran too long for the chosen example in my answer. So the more fundamental question of whether it "can be done perfectly" in all cases may have to be left to the mathematicians.

Comment: It should be mentioned that there still are obtuse triangles left in the refined mesh, so I'm not even sure if an obtuse-free meshing is possible: `Position[MeshPrimitives[%, 2] /. Polygon[p_] :> (Max[TriAngles[p]] < π/2), False]`. Of course, one can split the obtuse triangles right at the altitude perpendicular to their corresponding hypotenuses, but that might take more time to do.

Comment: @J.M. indeed, it certainly seems hard to prove that a simple iterative refinement will suffice.

Comment: Thanks, Jens, for figuring this out! @J.M., yes, still obtuse triangles. :-/ There are papers written on nonobtuse triangulations, so I know it can be achieved. But apparently not without implementing some of the algorithms in the literature. I was hoping to avoid a major implementation effort...

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke certainly not a trivial problem. But maybe something for Wolfram to implement in the future...

Comment: @J.M. Splitting obtuse triangles by the altitude requires then splitting the adjacent triangle sharing the same base, in order to achieve a proper triangulation mesh. And there can be cascades of splits caused by one split.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, the underlying triangulation algorithm is [triangle](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html). If it can be done based on that then it can be done in Mathematica. I don't think I'll implement anything outside of that. What is the application? I think there is bigger fish to fry.

Comment: @user21: My application is very specific to my narrow pursuits, and surely not of general interest.  The Shewchuk *triangle* code is fantastically useful, and I am grateful to have it so nicely implemented in Mathematica. If you are the implementer: Thanks!

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke, I can not take claim for implementing Triangle - I did, however, implement the link to Triangle  which you can find [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/TriangleLink/guide/TriangleLink.html). Also added another possible approach. Hope any of that helps.

Answer (score 8):

Here is another approach. Mathematica uses [Triangle](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html) as it's 2D mesh generator. Triangle is very efficient and returns good results for numerical routines like the Finite Element Method or interpolation functions. However, to the best of my knowledge, there is not way to tell Triangle to use not generate triangles that have a angles that are larger than a specified values. (One can request the opposite however, elements that have no angle smaller than a request value)

As another option, I'd suggest to use a different mesh generator. You can find [a port of Distmesh to Mathematica (contained in the FEMAddOns)](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns) and use that. FEMAddOns is easily installed by evaluating:

```
ResourceFunction["FEMAddOnsInstall"][]
```

Distmesh is different in that it generates extremely smooth meshes. Here is an example after you install the Distmesh port:

```
Needs["DistMesh`"]

r = Disk[{0, 0}, {3, 2}];
em = DistMesh[r];
```

Distmesh returns an `ElementMesh` but that is trivial to convert to `MeshRegion` if you want.

```
MeshRegion[em]
```

[image]

There are still a few elements that do not meet the criterion:

```
pos = Position[
  MeshPrimitives[mr, 2] /. 
   Polygon[p_] :> (Max[TriAngles[p]] < \[Pi]/2), False]
{{2}, {10}, {18}, {175}, {196}, {260}}

HighlightMesh[mr, {2, Flatten[pos]}]
```

[image]

But they are not too far off:

```
(Extract[MeshPrimitives[mr, 2], pos] /. 
   Polygon[p_] :> Max[TriAngles[p]] - \[Pi]/2)*180/\[Pi]
{5.925868726419833`, 7.006195348307825`, 1.9880526587495373`, \
2.3708695038708707`, 5.427334986621736`, 1.4924245044698656`}
```

If you have suggestions for improving / extending the Distmesh port,I'd love to see a pull request ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Something about your function `TriAngles` is interfering with `MeshRefinementFunction`.  If I evaluate `TriAngles` inside the  `MeshRefinementFunction`, then `MeshRefinementFunction` is ignored, even when the output of `TriAngles` isn't used.

```
DiscretizeRegion[Disk[], MeshRefinementFunction -> Function[{vlist, area}, N@TriAngles[vlist]; If[area < 0.001, Return[False], Return[True]]]]
```

But if I comment it out, `MeshRefinementFunction` behaves as desired.

```
DiscretizeRegion[Disk[], MeshRefinementFunction -> Function[{vlist, area}, N(*@TriAngles*)[vlist];If[area < 0.001, Return[False], Return[True]]]]
```

Comment: I don't think the function `Triangles` is broken. It's just not written very cleanly, but that can't be why the function is essentially ignored.

Comment: I'll rephrase "broken"-->"interfering".

Comment: I have a different interpretation of what's going on, and with some changes to the `MeshRefinementFunction` call the original function definition can actually be made to work.

Comment: @Jens: Thanks to you both for your attention. I don't see why TriAngles[] should interfere... Note that I ignore the area in the `fob` function, which presumably is my prerogative.